# Prevent overwriting values in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do i prevent overwriting my values in the following scenario.

I am reading through each row of an Excel file saving my prices and products in two lists and then using the zip functionality to combine these two lists with a third one.

```
        for (var productsPricesStock in zip([
          products,
          prices,
          row.sublist(3, maxCols),
        ])) {
          standValues[productsPricesStock[0]] = {
            'name': productsPricesStock[0].toString(),
            'price': productsPricesStock[1].toString(),
            'stock': productsPricesStock[2].toString(),
          };
        }
```

I then save this Map of Values

```
        if (!startingStock[tourNumber].contains(standName)) {
          Map standObject = {standName: standValues};
          startingStock[tourNumber].add(standObject);
        }
```

My problem is that my entries are overwritten with the values of the next ones:
This is the first entry of the first row for example:

[image]

This is first entry of the second row:

[image]

As you can see here the first row has now the same entry as the second:

[image]

And this will happen for each row which means in the end all rows have the value of the last one.

I am pretty sure it has something to do with storing references to values instead of values but i am not sure how to prevent that.

Help is highly appreciated !

Full code of function:

```
  List<dynamic> products = [];
  List<dynamic> prices = [];
  Map<String, dynamic> startingStock = {};
  Map<String, dynamic> standValues = {};

 Future<void> _readExcel() async {
    try {
      var bytes = _tempFile.readAsBytesSync();
      var excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);
      for (var table in excel.tables.keys) {
        int maxCols = excel.tables[table].maxCols;
        for (var row in excel.tables[table].rows) {
          if (row[2] == 'Produkt') {
            row.removeWhere(
                (product) => product == null || product == 'Produkt');
            products = row;
          }
          if (row[2] == 'Preis') {
            row.removeWhere((price) =>
                price == null || price == 'Stand' || price == 'Preis');
            prices = row;
          }
        }
        for (var row in excel.tables[table].rows) {
          if (row[0] != 'TP-Master' && row[0] != null && row[1] != null) {
            var tourNumber = row[0].toString();
            var standName = row[1].toString();
            if (!startingStock.containsKey(tourNumber)) {
              startingStock[tourNumber] = [];
            }

            if (!startingStock[tourNumber].contains(standName)) {
              Map standObject = {standName: standValues};
              startingStock[tourNumber].add(standObject);
            }

            for (var productsPricesStock in zip([
              products,
              prices,
              row.sublist(3, maxCols),
            ])) {
              standValues[productsPricesStock[0]] = {
                'name': productsPricesStock[0].toString(),
                'price': productsPricesStock[1].toString(),
                'stock': productsPricesStock[2].toString(),
              };
            }
          }
        }
      }
      successSnackBar('Die Datei wurde erfolgreich gelesen!');
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
      errorSnackBar('Beim lesen der Datei ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!');
    }
  }
```

This is an extract of the excel-file.

In row 5 you can see all the products.
In row 6 you can see the prices of each product.
In the rows afterwards you can see in the first column the tour-number and the associated shop-name plus the amount the shop has of each product.

In my code i try to store my data in the format tournumber[shopname] and then map the price, productname and amount of products.
[image]

Excel for testing:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p9Z5yQ2u8sVDmEdbD9dYyYPwlQqdXWeZJp2BjvoexU4/edit?usp=sharing

The result would look like this:
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

This is how the lists and Maps would look like after execution with the example excel.

```
    products = [
Spargel W, 
Spargel V, 
gestrig Spargel W, 
gestrigSpargel V, 
Erdbeer 1,  
Erdbeer 2
]
    prices = [10.90, 8.90, x, x, x, 2,50 ]
    startingStock = {
    'T1' : [U-Stephansplatz[
    Spargel W: {
    'name': Spargel W,
     'price': '10.9', 
    'stock': '30'
    }
    Spargel V: {
    ...
    } 
    Spargel W gestern: {
    ...
    } 
    ...
    ],
    Rugenbarg[
    Spargel W: {...}, 
    Spargel V: {...} 
    Spargel W gestern: {...} 
    ...]
    ] ...
    , 'T2': [
    Volksdorf : [
    Spargel W: {
    'name': Spargel W, 
    'price': '10.9', 
    'stock': '45'
    }
    Spargel V: {
    ...
    }
    Spargel W gestern: {
    ...
    } 
    ...],
    Poppenbüttel [
    Spargel W: {...}, 
    Spargel V: {...} 
    Spargel W gestern: {...} 
    ...]
    ] ...}
```

standValues contains only for the current row the values so in this case it would contain the values of the last row. (T2 stand Fuhle Nord )

```
standValues = [Spargel W: {name: Spargel W, price: 10.9, stock: 23} Spargel V: ..., Spargel W gestrig: ..., ...]
```

Comment: The line `Map standObject = {standName: standValues};` seems problematic since you are sharing the same Map instance for all created `standObject`. Is than intentional?

Comment: This looks like the problem but i am not sure how i would assign my standValues to the correct standName otherwise. 
This results in the same result:
 startingStock[tourNumber].add({standName: standValues});

Comment: Would love to give a solution for you but I don't have enough details for knowing what you are trying to accomplish. Also, the code requires an example excel file before it makes sense to try execute the code.

Comment: I tried to add more information if there is anything unclear just let me know!

Comment: Could you try write in details what you expect `products`, `prices`, `startingStock` and `standValues` to contain after running through your example excel document?

Comment: I added how it looks like in firebase with the data and how it would look like in the lists and maps. 
( I edited the firebase stock entries to be correct )

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it. :)

Comment: If anything is unclear, you have a question or need some more code hit me up.
Thank you for trying ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some refactoring of your code and cleaned up some types so they are more specific. I hope this is close to what you want:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:quiver/iterables.dart';
import 'package:excel/excel.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await _readExcel();
}

Future<void> _readExcel() async {
  final startingStock =
      <String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>{};

  try {
    final bytes = File('StackOverflow.xlsx').readAsBytesSync();
    final excel = Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);

    for (final table in excel.tables.values) {
      final products = <String>[];
      final prices = <String>[];

      for (final row in table.rows) {
        if (row[2] == 'Produkt') {
          row.removeWhere(
              (Object product) => product == null || product == 'Produkt');
          products.addAll(row.map((Object e) => e.toString()));
        }
        if (row[2] == 'Preis') {
          row.removeWhere((Object price) =>
              price == null || price == 'Stand' || price == 'Preis');
          prices.addAll(row.map((Object e) => e.toString()));
        }
      }

      for (final row in table.rows) {
        if (row[0] != 'TP-Master' && row[0] != null && row[1] != null) {
          final tourNumber = row[0].toString();
          final standName = row[1].toString();
          final standValues = startingStock
              .putIfAbsent(tourNumber, () => {})
              .putIfAbsent(standName, () => {});

          for (final productsPricesStock in zip<dynamic>([
            products,
            prices,
            row.sublist(3, table.maxCols),
          ])) {
            standValues[productsPricesStock[0].toString()] = {
              'name': productsPricesStock[0].toString(),
              'price': productsPricesStock[1].toString(),
              'stock': productsPricesStock[2].toString(),
            };
          }
        }
      }
    }
    print(json.encode(startingStock));
    print('Die Datei wurde erfolgreich gelesen!');
  } catch (err) {
    print(err);
    print('Beim lesen der Datei ist ein Fehler aufgetreten!');
  }
}
```

Output in formatted JSON:

```
{
   "T1":{
      "U-Stephansplatz":{
         "Spargel W":{
            "name":"Spargel W",
            "price":"10.9",
            "stock":"30.0"
         },
         "Spargel V":{
            "name":"Spargel V",
            "price":"8.9",
            "stock":"12.0"
         },
         "Spargel W gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel W gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Spargel V gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel V gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 1":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 1",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 2":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 2",
            "price":"2.5",
            "stock":"0.0"
         }
      },
      "Rugenbarg":{
         "Spargel W":{
            "name":"Spargel W",
            "price":"10.9",
            "stock":"25.0"
         },
         "Spargel V":{
            "name":"Spargel V",
            "price":"8.9",
            "stock":"124.0"
         },
         "Spargel W gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel W gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Spargel V gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel V gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 1":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 1",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 2":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 2",
            "price":"2.5",
            "stock":"34.0"
         }
      },
      "Blankenese":{
         "Spargel W":{
            "name":"Spargel W",
            "price":"10.9",
            "stock":"22.0"
         },
         "Spargel V":{
            "name":"Spargel V",
            "price":"8.9",
            "stock":"12.0"
         },
         "Spargel W gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel W gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Spargel V gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel V gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 1":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 1",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 2":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 2",
            "price":"2.5",
            "stock":"21.0"
         }
      },
      "Altona ZOB":{
         "Spargel W":{
            "name":"Spargel W",
            "price":"10.9",
            "stock":"22.0"
         },
         "Spargel V":{
            "name":"Spargel V",
            "price":"8.9",
            "stock":"42.0"
         },
         "Spargel W gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel W gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Spargel V gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel V gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 1":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 1",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 2":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 2",
            "price":"2.5",
            "stock":"22.0"
         }
      },
      "Holstenstraße":{
         "Spargel W":{
            "name":"Spargel W",
            "price":"10.9",
            "stock":"11.0"
         },
         "Spargel V":{
            "name":"Spargel V",
            "price":"8.9",
            "stock":"24.0"
         },
         "Spargel W gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel W gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Spargel V gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel V gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 1":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 1",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 2":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 2",
            "price":"2.5",
            "stock":"65.0"
         }
      }
   },
   "T2":{
      "Volksdorf":{
         "Spargel W":{
            "name":"Spargel W",
            "price":"10.9",
            "stock":"45.0"
         },
         "Spargel V":{
            "name":"Spargel V",
            "price":"8.9",
            "stock":"34.0"
         },
         "Spargel W gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel W gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Spargel V gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel V gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 1":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 1",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 2":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 2",
            "price":"2.5",
            "stock":"4.0"
         }
      },
      "Poppenbüttel":{
         "Spargel W":{
            "name":"Spargel W",
            "price":"10.9",
            "stock":"34.0"
         },
         "Spargel V":{
            "name":"Spargel V",
            "price":"8.9",
            "stock":"435.0"
         },
         "Spargel W gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel W gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Spargel V gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel V gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 1":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 1",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 2":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 2",
            "price":"2.5",
            "stock":"43.0"
         }
      },
      "Erdkampsweg":{
         "Spargel W":{
            "name":"Spargel W",
            "price":"10.9",
            "stock":"23.0"
         },
         "Spargel V":{
            "name":"Spargel V",
            "price":"8.9",
            "stock":"34.0"
         },
         "Spargel W gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel W gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Spargel V gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel V gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 1":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 1",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 2":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 2",
            "price":"2.5",
            "stock":"5.0"
         }
      },
      "Drosselstraße":{
         "Spargel W":{
            "name":"Spargel W",
            "price":"10.9",
            "stock":"432.0"
         },
         "Spargel V":{
            "name":"Spargel V",
            "price":"8.9",
            "stock":"53.0"
         },
         "Spargel W gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel W gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Spargel V gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel V gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 1":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 1",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 2":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 2",
            "price":"2.5",
            "stock":"6.0"
         }
      },
      "Fuhle Nord ":{
         "Spargel W":{
            "name":"Spargel W",
            "price":"10.9",
            "stock":"23.0"
         },
         "Spargel V":{
            "name":"Spargel V",
            "price":"8.9",
            "stock":"34.0"
         },
         "Spargel W gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel W gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Spargel V gestrig":{
            "name":"Spargel V gestrig",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 1":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 1",
            "price":"x",
            "stock":"0.0"
         },
         "Erdbeer 2":{
            "name":"Erdbeer 2",
            "price":"2.5",
            "stock":"0.0"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: just tested it works like a charm! Thank you so much i was stuck on this for quite some time. 
I will definitely accept this as the answer if you have some time could you maybe quickly explain what the error was and how to prevent it in the future?

Comment: I think the root of most of your problems comes from scope issues. I know there are different schools of how variables should be declared but I think it is best to restrict the number of available variables by defining the variables in the scope they are needed. This will prevent a lot of cases where values of variable are reused the wrong places. I also added more static typing to make it easier for me to ensure I used the right types the right places.

Comment: And at last, I changed some of your logic for initialize new maps to use `putIfAbsent` which is a great method where you can easily get a value from a map but also insert a value in the map if it is not already defined.

Comment: Thank you again for your help! I will take this into account :) 
Have a nice day.